# Creating Wix CustomAction in VS2015 and not able to identify the Tag WixCATargetsPath

Tags: .net, wix, wix3.5

I am creating Wix CustomAction from VS2015 as it is given here.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132918/Creating-Custom-Action-for-WIX-Written-in-Managed?fid=1599130&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&spc=Relaxed&select=4131367&fr=1#xx0xx

I have installed WIX Installer and able to access  Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll library.

But when I am trying to add **WixCATargetsPath** to the PropertyGroup section in the project file, it says it has Invalid Child Element. I am following instructions as t is given in the above link.

```
<WixCATargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixCATargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.0\Wix.CA.targets</WixCATargetsPath>
```

Any have any thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your project file to see if the Property is placed correctly

Comment: What error message are you facing @Ritha? I'm posting an answer below that help me resolved the issue. Maybe it help others too.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue and resolved it by checking two things.

1. If you are using ToolsVersion "14.0" then please use following line of code:

   $(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.CA.targets
2. Make sure above line of code is in single line and should not span in more than one line.

Save the project file and reload the project. 
Hope this would help.